# Understanding bitwise operations

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

This code segment:

```
(x >>> 3) & ((1 << 5) - 1)
```

apparently results in a 5-bit integer with bits 3 - 7 of `x`.

How would you go about understanding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at `((1 << 5) - 1)` first.

- `1 << 5` is equal to `100000` in binary.
- When we subtract 1, we're left with `11111`, a binary number of five 1s.

Now, it's important to understand that `a & 0b11111` is an operation that keeps only the 5 least significant bits of `a`. Recall that the `&` of two bits is 1 if and only if both of the bits are 1. Any bits in `a` above the 5th bit, therefore, will become 0, since `bit & 0 == 0`. Moreover, all of the bits from bit 1 to bit 5 will retain their original value, since `bit & 1 == bit` (`0 & 1 == 0` and `1 & 1 == 1`).

Now, because we shift the bits of `x` in `x >>> 3` down by 3, losing the three least significant bits of `x`, we are applying the process above to bits 4 to 8 (starting at index 1). Hence, the result of the operation retains only those bits (if we say the first bit is bit 0, then that would indeed be bit 3 to bit 7, as you've stated).

---

Let's take an example: `1234`. In binary, that's `10011010010`. So, we start with the shift by 3:

```
10011010010 >>> 3 = 10011010
```

Essentially we just trim off the last 3 bits. Now we can perform the `&` operation:

```
  10011010
& 00011111
  --------
  00011010
```

So, our final result is `11010`. As you can see, the result is as expected:

```
bits  |  1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
index | 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
               ^-------^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(x >>> 3)
```

Shifts `x` right 3 bits logically, i.e. not sign-extending at the left. The lower-order 3 bits are lost. (This is equivalent to an unsigned division by 8.)

```
1 << 5
```

Shifts `1` left 5 bits, i.e. multiplies it by 32, yielding `0b00000000000000000000000000100000.`

```
-1
```

Subtracts one from that, giving 31, or `0b00000000000000000000000000011111.`

```
&
```

ANDs these together, yielding only the lower-order 5 bits of the result of `x >>> 3`, in other words bits 3..7 of the original `x.`

Answer (score 1):

> "How would you go about understanding this?".

I assume that you are actually asking how *you* should go about understanding it.  (As distinct from someone just explaining it to you ...)

The way to understand it is to "hand execute" it.

- Get a piece of paper and a pencil.
- Based on your understanding of how Java operator precedence works, figure out the order in which the operations will be performed.
- Based on your understanding of each operator, write the input patterns of bits on the piece of paper and "hand execute" each operation ... in the correct order.

If you do this a few times with a few values of `x`, you should get to understand why this expression gives you a 5 bit number.

If you repeat this exercise for a few other examples, you should get to the point where you don't need to go through the tedious process of working it out with a pencil and paper.

I see that @arshajii has essentially done this for you for this example.  But I think you will get a deeper understanding if you do / repeat the work for yourself.

---

One thing to remember about integer and bitwise operations in Java is that the operations are always performed using 32 or 64 bit operations ... even if the operands are 8 or 16 bit.  Another thing to remember (though it is not relevant here) is that the right hand operand of a shift operator is chopped to 5 or 6 bits, depending on whether this is a 32 or 64 bit operation.

Comment: Ok Stephen, I'll look at some other bit manipulation code and try to understand what it does. Thank you!